# Saving a proper timestamp in database django 2+/python 3.5

Tags: python, django

I have a table:

```
scan_start = timezone.now()
    class TSForm(models.Model):   
        sBegin = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
        sEnd = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
        FKToUser = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

When I go to save this in my python file like:

```
scan_start = timezone.now()
tfh = TSForm(sBegin=scan_start,FKToUser=historyUser)
```

It properly saves the other fields, but it is saving the `sBegin` as:
`2018-05-25 00:00:00.000000` instead of say: `2018-05-25 10:05:23.321231`

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What's the value `scan_start`?

Comment: @Lemayzeur - See above for added code

Comment: Did you have that field as `DateField` before switching it to `DateTimeField`?

Comment: @Lemayzeur yeah I did.

Comment: the database may keep the same behavior of DateField, so if you don't have sensitive data in that field, I suggest that to remove it `makemigration & migrate`, and re-add it

Comment: @Lemayzeur - ok I'll try to mess around with it more

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work. Its inserting a "`datetime`" of `2018-05-25 04:00:00.000000`

Comment: did you actually remove the field, and then run makemigrations & migrate?